# Javascript, multiply the last loop number

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multiplication

Ok, maybe is a noob and ridicolous question but I've a little problem.

I made a simple for loop that sum in a particular way some number, I need to sum the pow of one number. It's all good if I don't use the IncrementPercent, so if IcrementPercent is 0 I got this:

```
test - divider: 2
test - divider: 6
test - divider: 18
test - divider: 54
test - divider: 162
test - divider: 486
test - divider: 1458
```

And that for me is correct, but if I activate the IncrementPercent at 10, so each time the number must be incremented by 1.1 and so on, I've this

```
test - divider: 2.2
test - divider: 6.6000000000000005
test - divider: 19.8
test - divider: 59.400000000000006
test - divider: 178.20000000000002
test - divider: 534.6
test - divider: 1603.8000000000002
```

And this's not correct for me, because I need this

```
test - divider: 2.2
test - divider: 7.26
test - divider: 23.958
test - divider: 79.0614
... and so on
```

So the idea is simple, I have a starting number, in that case is 2, so I need to multiply it for 3 the 1st time, for 3*3 the 2nd time, for 3*3*3 the 3rd time ...

But if I activate the IncrementPercent I want to do this:

```
2*1.1 -> 2.2
2.2*3*1.1 -> 7.26
7.26*3*3*1.1 -> 23.958
```

So each time is the previous number that I've to multiply!

This is the formula that I've:

```
IncrementPercent = 10;
mult1 = 2;
mult2 = 3;
Game = 7;

var divider = 1 + (mult1 * (1 + (IncrementPercent / 100))) - mult1;
for (i = 0; i <= (Game - 1); i++) {
var divider = mult1 * Math.pow(mult2, i) * (1 + (IncrementPercent / 100));
console.log('test - divider: ' + divider);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were overcomplicating:

```
var incrementPercent = 10,
    number = 2,
    factor = 3,
    iterations = 7;
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
  number *= 1 + incrementPercent/100;
  console.log(number);
  number *= factor;
}
```

Comment: Also consider `totalFactor = factor * (1 + incrementPercent) / 100` and then only do one multiplication at each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Tnx for your help, but I also need to return the sum of iteration, so if I use 1 iteration the total is 2, for 2 iteration the total is 8 and so on. I'm not a programmer sorry.